# Analysing melodies with mathematics

Tags: composition, melody

I am doing a statistics project in which I analyze the most streamed songs on Spotify to create one based on the data I get. I analyze the harmony, structure, key, tempo... I just don't know how to analyze the melodies in a way that I can use to create a "perfect" one. Does anyone how I could do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Impossible - one man's perfect tune is another's nightmare!

Comment: Actually such analyzes are done. Yes, definition of "perfect song" is ambiguous, but for obvious reasons people are interested in e.g. what songs sell the best. Not writing it as an answer, because I can't provide any references rn, but yes, look up the existing analyzes, see what criteria people used. For melodies you can attempt looking at the ambitus, at the size of intervals used, at the use of chord and non-chord tones, at the rhythmic values and mobility, at the shape and direction of the melody...

Comment: This is an interesting idea, although maybe you should call it a "most typical" song rather than a "perfect" one

Comment: What kind of a movie do you get if you morph together the scripts, actors and cinematography of all movies ever made. Will it be a comedy or action movie? A documentary perhaps? Maybe a sports movie? Will it be _good_?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica as far as I understand, that's how Netflix original shows are made, so you can check there how it works. Also, there are more sophisticated statistical methods than taking average.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an ad hoc opinion from someone who never did any statistical music analysis. I would try to do some kind of feature extraction from the note/interval data. The features would be found by or together with relating the ups, downs, highs, lows, strong, weak etc. to the harmonic, rhythmic and structural aspects. This feature extraction phase would produce features such as chord-tone vs. non-chord-tone, tension/resolution, off-beat/on-beat, and where these are located in the larger structure of the song form. Things that an actual song writer would consider as features of a melody.

What kind of a form does the song and the melody have - is it like a limerick? AABA or some other form? 12-bar blues? Where, relative to the macro structure are the important melodic features located? For how long does the song prolong waiting for a resolution? Is the resolution provided by a lead melody or backing chords? Does the melody sway together with backing harmony changes? Or is the lead line neutral pentatonics and harmonic swaying has been added in the arrangement?

The harmonic aspect here can be slightly ambiguous, because it can be provided by a melody alone - if it is a "melodic" melody in the sense that it implies harmonic changes. How much of the harmony comes from a lead instrument or singer, and how much comes from other instruments? Are there other instruments to begin with? A lot of the time, a completely colorless, odorless, neutral melody can be made to taste like something by adding a backing chord progression. But if you heard the melody alone, it wouldn't make you feel much of anything. Or your lead melody could be like Happy Birthday, which implies quite clear harmonic changes of balance even if sung or played without any accompaniment. The lead melody also implies a clear meter! No drums or chordal instruments needed, a melody can carry the whole package all by itself.

To make your statistics understand modern music, it would be good if it could handle rap as a melody. Or completely rhythmic melodies. The opening beat of Queen's We Will Rock You is a very strong leading musical element and I would call it a melody. It has two unclear pitches in a strong rhythm. It is so melodic, any non-musician can "hum" it or play it by hitting objects.

Also pay attention to rap melodies - the way the pitches change in rap. Quite often, rap is centered on defined notes and it could even be transcribed as staff notation.

Comment: I'll need to add the caveat that, rather like your earlier comment "What kind of a movie do you get if you morph together the scripts, actors and cinematography of all movies ever made. Will it be a comedy or action movie? A documentary perhaps? Maybe a sports movie? Will it be *good*?", such a melodic analysis needs to be accompanied by a step back to analyze whether the most streamed songs on Spotify have tempos and genres in common. Both tempo and genre splits are enough to need to come up with multiple melodies to emulate the analyzed music instead of only one melody.

Comment: As an example, take analyzing (classical) piano sonatas and composing your own based on them. Seems fairly silly to compose a single-movement piece as a result that averages out all those sonata movements' tempos, right? Even a single-movement piece that preserves the typical tempos of sonata movements in order would do a better job (then the massive debate of whether to have a dance movement in the first place and/or put it third or second begins).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you take a look at the [Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)
and the DFT / FFT Algorithm. There are dozens of libraries that implement this in many programming languages.

You can find an amazing explenation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY). It basically takes a soundwave and returns the frequencies in a specific time span. This way, you could analyse the songs for their chord progressions, keys, etc. You could even use it to measure the Tempo by measuring how far different beats are apart.

However, it depends on how much time you have and how many songs you have to analyze. If you only need to analyze a few songs, I would suggest just looking at each song manually and identifying the chords, tempo and melody individually. If you want to analyze a lot of songs, I would heavily suggest building a program using the FFT, that does this for you.

Good Luck!

Answer (score -2):

In the kind of music you're analyzing, it is dubious (at best) to analyze melodies independent of their harmonic and metric/rhythmic contexts. However, by consider melody as an isolated element, it's possible that the "average" or "best" melody will create its own harmonic and rhythmic identity, unique from its source material. (It's also possible it will just be aurally random pitches and durations).

Melodies in isolation are more-or-less defined by the distance (interval) and direction from one note to the next, plus duration of each note. So two possibilities come to mind.

1. Use vectors to represent the motion from one note to the next.
2. Construct continuous functions to represent the melodies.

You would create a statistical analysis the decide things like number of notes, total duration, and "best" movement from the first note to the second (e.g., the "ideal vector",  and so forth.)

<sub>Given the source material, I would put my money on the statistical outcome being a single pitch held for about 3 minutes</sub>

Comment: I'm interested in taking the bet.

Comment: @user1079505 I'll bet you an upvote. (Meanwhile, any thoughts on what the "ideal" statistical melody would wind up being?)

Comment: Thinking that a melody is defined by intervals and durations feels intuitively just wrong. A melody implies harmony and rhythm, and the perception of these depends on subjective interpretations of things like where a tonal center is and what the meter and pulse are. All of these can be changed upside-down by a single change in the first interval or duration in the chain. If you write the same interval+duration sequence in bars of 3/4 instead of 4/4, it's a big change, isn't it.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I agree, but the core problem lies in OP's approach to the problem. It's clear OP is defining melody as only the individual notes comprising that melody, without consideration for the other factors that give that melody meaning.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica It's also worth pointing out that the idea that melody implies harmony is fairly unique to Western music, and then only Western music of the past few hundred years. Most other musical cultures don't have the same concepts of harmony, and melodies are more truly linear.

Comment: From the OP's post: 1. "I analyze the harmony, structure, key, tempo" – it's clear they aim to analyze multiple aspects of composition. 2. "I analyze the most streamed songs on Spotify" – it's also clear they focus on modern popular Western music.

Comment: @user1079505 It's equally clear that OP is analyzing them separately. "I analyze the harmony, [etc.] ... I just don't know how to analyze the melodies."

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure I follow. Intervals are a part of harmony. An interval of a minor third sounds like a minor third, it's a harmonic thing already by itself. Every interval has a harmonic aspect. If the music has pitch intervals, it has a harmonic dimension. Maybe it's more rigid and static like a mode, and not something that could be modeled in terms of "chord changes", but there is a structure or organization of pitch relationships.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica The idea of chord changes is a fundamentally Western idea of the past few hundred years. It's true that vertical structure can be imposed on any linear sequence of pitches, but it isn't a necessity. Indian music, for example, does not concern itself with verticality, nor does Gamelan. OP in this case is clearly looking at melody strictly as a linear sequence of pitches and is not concerned with any vertical implications of that sequence. It may be a poor way to analyze Western music (I've updated my post to reflect that), but it is, nonetheless *a* way to analyze it.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Come to think of it, divorcing melody from harmony could yield interesting results, especially since the same set of pitches can be harmonized in multiple ways. By considering melody and harmony independently, the result has the potential both to be musically nonsensical or musically quite interesting. It would depend on whether the "perfect" melody and "perfect" harmony turn out to align or not. It would be interesting to know whether they do or not.

Comment: I tried to say that music that doesn't have the kind of harmonic changes of balance that are modeled in terms of chord changes, does not have the kind of harmonic changes of balance  that are modeled in terms of chord changes. And then you reply by saying the same thing. But it is still harmony. Even static harmony that doesn't have changes of balance is harmony. Intervals build harmonic structures. Even if it does not change balance like in chord changes, it is still harmony. Intervals are building blocks for harmony. If there is a pitch, there is something in the harmonic field.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica It sounds like we agree on the presence of "harmony"; I'm only saying that for the kind of analysis OP is trying to do, the harmonic aspect does not need to be considered for the purpose of mathematically modeling the melody. Whether it's a valid analysis aside, OP is nevertheless asking how to do it, and I believe I've answered that question.